# Loading 26 letter images from a PNG stripe using BitmapRegionDecoder

Tags: android, android-bitmap, bitmapregiondecoder

In [a word game app](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q6/MyStripe/) I am trying to load 26 letter tiles from [a 6205 x 240 PNG image](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q6/MyStripe/res/drawable-xxhdpi/big_english.png):

```
private Paint mPaint = new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);

mStripe = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
    context.getResources(), R.drawable.big_english);
int h = mStripe.getHeight();
mSrc = new Rect(0, 0, h, h);
mDst = new Rect(0, 0, h, h);

canvas.drawBitmap(mStripe, mSrc, mDst, mPaint);
```

On the real device (Moto G) this fails with (I guess 1.5x downscaled from `drawables-xxhdpi`):

> OpenGLRenderer Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (4137 x
>   160; max=4096x4096)

and the letter images aren't displayed (the dragged tile appears to be empty):

[image: Moto G photo]

So I would like to use [BitmapRegionDecoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapRegionDecoder.html) to load 240 x 240 bitmaps, but as an Android programming newbie (and I have searched around too) I still have 2 questions please:

1. How to load a `R.drawable.big_english` - there is no suitable constructor?
2. Can I somehow use `isShareable` here - given the fact that I load 26 letters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitmapfonts for android http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/games/canvas/using-bitmap-fonts/

You should also google for bit map fonts. There are a few more implementations and examples.

For gl there's an implementation in libgdx http://www.codehead.co.uk/blog/android-bitmap-font-renderer-text-scaling-feature/